# Smarty - same template different content

Tags: foreach, smarty

What is the strategy in smarty for using different variables each time a template is included in another template?

Here is what I mean.
I have a smarty template that creates a simple navigation list.

```
    <ul class='linkList'>

  <li>

    <h3>{$title}</h3>

    <ul>
      {foreach $links as $d}
        <li><a title='{$d...}' href='{$d....}'>{$d.text}</a></li>
      {/foreach}
    </ul>

  </li>

</ul>
```

I want to include it a number of times in my main template and each time pass it different values. Im not sure what strategy to use to do this.

If I assign variables in my php file like this

```
$smarty->assign('links',array(.....);
$smarty->assign('title','My first link list');

$smarty->assign('links',array(different values);
$smarty->assign('title','My second link list');
```

and then include the template twice i will just get the same list twice with the second lot of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{include}` tag allows you to pass variables in the call:

```
{include 'linklist.tpl' title="Sample Links 1" links=$link_array1}
{include 'linklist.tpl' title="Sample Links 2" links=$link_array2}
```

Otherwise, I'm pretty sure you can use either `{assign}` or the short form of assign (`{$var=value}`) before including the template.